# Getting Value From Another Scene's Script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, scripting, integer

I'm beginner in Unity and trying to create a guessing number game.
In first scene, I have 2 input fields and player will write lower and upper limit. I'll keep that variables as "inputmin" and "inputmax" in a script.
In second scene, I want my game use those 2 variables as lower and upper limit. Tried to use "DontDestroyOnLoad" method, in game it passes the variables as dontdestroy object but I don't know how to use them in second scene's script. A little confusing text i wrote i guess i hope someone can help :)

Comment: Search for `Singleton` and apply it

Answer (score 0):

For an object that has DontDestroyOnLoad, get your script via `yourobject.GetComponent<MinMaxScript>()`
And you will be able to get data from your script.

Or you can use Singleton, or save and load data from a file.

Comment: Thanks, should I add any library for that method? Because i tried it but it didn't work. I mean, in first scene, i put my script which one is holding values in an object named "Limiter". In second scene's script, I wrote "Limiter.GetComponent<GetInput>();" but didn't work. GetInput is the first scene's value holder script's name.